# Laravel: Whats the difference between these two route api approach

Tags: laravel, cors, middleware

This

```
Route::middleware(['cors'])->group(function () {

    Route::post('/login', 'AuthController@APIstore');

    Route::middleware(['auth:api'])->group(function () {

        Route::post('/logout', 'AuthController@APIdestroy');

        Route::get('/projects', 'ProjectController@getAll');

    });

});
```

And this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function() {

    Route::post('/login', 'AuthController@APIstore');

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {

        Route::post('/logout', 'AuthController@APIdestroy');

        Route::get('/projects', 'ProjectController@getAll');

    });

});
```

On the first code, CORS middleware works with /login but does not work for /logout and /projects

On the second code, the CORS middleware does not work at all

is there a reason behind this?

Comment: And what does your `cors` middleware do buddy?

Comment: these are the same ... just run a `php artisan route:list` and see what middleware is attached to your routes

Answer (score 1):

So, as per the [Laravel Routing Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-groups), the top level middleware is applied to all groups in the group. So using `Route::middleware(['cors'])` will mean this middleware will be applied to `Route::middleware(['auth:api'])`.

However `Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors']` is a group route not a middleware route, so the middle is not applied to child groups.

Comment: "middleware is applied to all groups in the group" ... then the next paragraph ... except for your groups, because they are groups ?